# Jquery UI Sortable + Bootstrap variable height Divs sorting issue

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-draggable

Need your Help for fixing the issue regarding UI Sortable with bootstrap,I can achieve this sortable functionality in bootstrap but still there is a issue not able to fix by myself. My Fiddle link : `http://jsfiddle.net/wrtfp513/`

**Issue** : Here(check my fiddle) I divided into three parts(.part1,.part2,.part3) I can sort my 'Test' contents anywhere within these three parts  but when I sort all 'Test' contents into 'part1' there is an issue 'Not able to sort into .part2 as well as .part3 respectively'

My Code :

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="drag_holder" class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 part1">
           <div class="col-lg-12 drag_content"> 
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                  <div class="panel-heading">Test 1</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting indu  Ipsum.</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12 drag_content"> 
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                  <div class="panel-heading">Test 2</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">Contfghfghent</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12 drag_content"> 
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                  <div class="panel-heading">Test 3</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 part2">
             <div class="col-lg-12 drag_content"> 
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                  <div class="panel-heading">Test 4</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">Content</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12 drag_content"> 
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                  <div class="panel-heading">Test 5</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.  </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-4  part3">
            <div class="col-lg-12 drag_content"> 
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                  <div class="panel-heading">Test 6</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">Content</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12 drag_content"> 
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                  <div class="panel-heading">Test 7</div>
                  <div class="panel-body">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.   1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type  t  </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>
</div>
```

Script :

```
$(function () {
var demos =$("#drag_holder");
    demos.sortable({
         items: ".drag_content",
       placeholder: "panel"
    });

});
```

Thanks In Advance Guys..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now you are using Jquery UI for drag and drop (sortable). I understand your issue. This may be a issue in Jquery UI that you are pointing out. So Instead of using this(Jquery UI), You could use the **dragula.js** for the drag and drop functionality. It has an awesome feature while placing the target element with its shadow.

Check here: http://bevacqua.github.io/dragula/